# Ordering of SET OPTIONS and BEGIN END

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

It's a best practice to put SET OPTIONS at the top of a stored proc. It's also a best practice to have BEGIN and END wrap the entire stored proc body. Should the SET OPTIONS be wrapped in BEGIN/END, or does it not matter?

I.e.:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
BEGIN
...
END
```

or

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
...
END
```

Comment: BEGIN/END in the body of a procedure is really just noise. It isn't required and provides no tangible benefit. I would however use that READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level with extreme caution. That is NOT a magic go faster button.

Comment: @Sean Respectfully disagree about noise. BEGIN/END wrappers give a very clear visual separation, most importantly where the procedure body ends. This can be very useful when visually parsing a script with many modules in it. I talk about this a bit [here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist). I do  agree about NOLOCK. See https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere and https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Comment: `BEGIN...END` maybe "noise" but it's extremely helpful at preventing misunderstandings about code flow.  If you have `BEGIN...END` there is no doubt what the preceding `IF ...` affects.

Comment: BEGIN/END is one of those things that has been discussed (sometimes rather heatedly) over the years and there is no clear winner. There are valid points on both side of the issue.

Comment: @Sean well, you stated "provides no tangible benefit" and I disagree with that claim, that's all.